# Dynamic Search in DataGridview using TextChanged Event

Tags: c#, entity-framework, search, datagridview

**C#**

I am Using Entity framework  to a  database

this is my code To search in Datagridview:

```
        private void TxtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chbxSearch.Checked)
            {
                string strpatt = "";
                strpatt = "Name";
                strpatt += "like'%" + txtName.Text.Replace("'", "") + "%'";
                ((DataTable)dgvadministration.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = strpatt;
            };
        }
```

**Error**
when type anything in text

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.'

Answer (score 0):

---

this Code Is working , thank U

```
          if (chbxSearch.Checked)
           {
               dgvadministration.DataSource = db.SalesNames.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(txtName.Text)).ToList();

           };
```